# How can I make my button in JOptionPane perform some action without closing it?

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I've got dialog in my project with 3 buttons and I want them to execute some code. I know that these methods return integer (different for every button) and i can use "if" instruction to check which button was pressed and to perform specific action. It works but at first it closes dialog which is not what I want. I'd like to close it only via 3rd button or [x].

```
public void popup(){
    JButton[] buttons = {new JButton("Save"),new JButton("Re-draw"),new JButton("Close")};
    if(results.size()==0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please fill all fields", "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else{
    JList<String> resultsList = new JList(results.toArray(new String[results.size()]));
    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, resultsList, "Results",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, buttons, buttons[0]);

        }
    });
    System.out.println(result);
        if (result == 0){
            /*saving results*/
        }
        else if(result == 1){
             draw();

        }
```

As i said, it works, but pressing any of button results in closing dialog. I dont know wheter its possible disable automatic dialog closing for buttons "Save" and "Redraw"?

Comment: Please include the minimal amount of code needed to demonstrate the problem in your question.

Comment: Without seeing code its hard to say, but I would wager... if you have a dialog, and that means you have the source... do the work you want in the click handler for the button in question.

Comment: Maybe give `showOptionPane` a shot rather than `showMessageDialog`? Have a look at "Creating and Showing Simple Dialogs" on this page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html page

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup).

The other option of course if to just create your own custom JDialog that implements the functionality you desire.